# SQL on removing middle initial

Tags: sql-server

If I have a `Name` column with values like `Jackson, BG Lisa F` and I only want to pull `BG Lisa` how would I do that?

```
 LEFT(SUBSTRING(a.member_name,
                CHARINDEX(',', a.member_name) + 1, LEN(a.member_name)),
                CHARINDEX(' ', 
                          SUBSTRING(a.member_name, CHARINDEX(',', a.member_name) + 1, LEN(a.member_name)))) AS 'Newborn First Name'
```

Comment: You need to give more examples of the kinds of names that can arise. Otherwise, you might get answers that don't consider all possibilities in your data. This is why questions should always include example input and desired output.

Comment: I can't help but post this here. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

Since you only gave a single example....

```
declare @name varchar(64) = 'Jackson, BG Lisa F'


select 
    left(right(@name,(len(@name) - charindex(',',@name))),len(right(@name,(len(@name) - charindex(',',@name)))) - 1)
```

Naturally this would return unexpected results if the last character wasn't there, or if you have a bunch of other name combinations. There are tons of questions on SO about parsing names from full names and what you'll discover is **the consensus is there isn't a catch all solution for everyone**. Different cultures have different number of names, use hyphens, use UNICODE characters, have them in different orders, use a delimiter only sometimes, etc. So, **the only way for you to get a solution that works for you 100% of the time is to list all possible combinations**--which usually isn't possible. Then, you will wind up with some ugly code like above.

Comment: Thank you so much!